# Named colors in R and ggvis

Tags: r, ggvis

I have encountered a problem with [R's named colors](https://sites.google.com/site/curtiskephart/r_colors) when I use the ggvis package. For example, if I set the ggvis fill property to "cadetblue" it works, but if I set it to "cadetblue1" it does not. Here is a small reproducible example:

```
library(ggvis)
pressure %>% ggvis(~temperature, ~pressure, fill := "cadetblue") %>% layer_bars()
```

When I change the fill property to "cadetblue1" the plot turns black. It seems only the major named colors without a number in the name works when using ggvis. Does anybody know why or have I misunderstood something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why that's happening, but you can use the named colors by converting from name to hexadecimal.

- `col2rgb` converts the color name to its 8-bit numeric rgb values (rendered in base 10).
- `rgb` takes the output of `col2rgb` (after conversion from a column vector to a row vector using `t` (transpose)) and converts them to the corresponding hexadecimal color code.

So, in your case, the code would be:

```
fill := rgb(t(col2rgb("cadetblue1")), maxColorValue=255)
```

Or, to see the individual steps:

```
x = t(col2rgb("cadetblue1"))
```

> ```
>      red green blue   
> [1,] 152   245  255
> ```

```
rgb(x, maxColorValue=255)
```

> ```
> [1] "#98F5FF"
> ```

Comment: Thank you for a helpful answer! Just one note: when I run your code RStudio IDE gives me a warning saying that `max` is a partially matched argument. Rather, it should be `maxColorValue`.

Comment: Yes, I was just being lazy. I've added the full argument name. R does matching on partial argument names, so it will work as long as there's not a conflict with another argument in the same function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any [HTML hex color code](http://htmlcolorcodes.com/) for colors.  For example, try

```
pressure %>% ggvis(~temperature, ~pressure, fill := "#FFFF00") %>% layer_bars()
```

For yellow or `"#5f9ea0"` for cadet blue, and so on...

The plot turns black because R doesn't recognize your color input as valid and it defaults to black.

Comment: Your answer does not really answer my question, sorry.

Comment: What is your question then, exactly?   You seem to have already answered your own question because you found that "only major named colors" are recognized.  You cannot just increment them by putting a number at the end of the string.

Comment: If my hypothesis is indeed correct, I would like to know why. I also would like to know if there is a solution to this problem, still using named colors, not hex.